# JavaScript gettes and setters

Tags: javascript

OK Im not getting this.

```
var customer = new Object;
customer._customerID = 0;
Object.defineProperty(customer, "customerID", {
    get: function() {
    if (_customerID > -1) {
        return this._customerID;
    } else {
        throw new Error("No valid customer ID is avaliable");
    }
    },
   set: function(id) {
    if(isNaN(id) || id %1 !== 0 || id < 0) {
    throw new Error("Custom ID must have a non-negative integer");
    }
    this._customerID = id;
}
});
```

What is the point of this code? when I use

> ```
> customer._customerID = 20;
> console.log (customer.customerID);
> ```

I get error _customerID is not defined. I'm not getting what is this supouse to go. I'm a bit new to javaScript dont be harsh -)

Comment: In the first line of the `get` function, `if (_customerID > -1)` should be `if (this._customerID > -1)`.

Comment: `customer.set(20);
    console.log (customer.get());`

Comment: The intent is to wrap the process of getting and setting the id so that you can do validations and such.  You want to always use it by calling `customer.set(20)`, not by accessing _customerID directly.

Comment: Since it's using `defineProperty`, why would explicit methods `get` and `set` be used? For me it's working as just `customer.customerID`...

Comment: In `customer._customerID = 20;`, you are bypassing the setter you've provided. I think you mean to use `customer.customerID = 20`: then your setter code will be called and verification done.

Comment: Thank you! It work now, but why to u tipe customer.set(20), when I try this way, I'm getting TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'set'. Beside that is working nicely.

Comment: yes but _ is does not have the power to realy make propertis hiden in javaScript, like some other languages, its just semantic. Thats why u can use __customerID and customerID to set the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the getter you are using the global `_customerID` variable, your get function should be:

```
function() {
  if (this._customerID > -1) {
    return this._customerID;
  } else {
    throw new Error("No valid customer ID is available");
  }
}
```